# Trouble with removing items from list

Tags: python, function

I'm having trouble getting this function to work. The purpose of it is to delete items from a list.

```
def sell(inventory_list):
    print()
    count = int(input('How many items would you like to sell? '))
    print()

    for count in range(count):
        print()
        type = input('Enter the type of item you wish to sell? ')
        print()
        name = input('Enter the name of the item you wish to sell? ')
        print()
        price = float(input('What is the price of the item you wish to sell? $'))

        items = Plant.SubPlant(type, name, price)

        inventory_list.remove(items)

    return inventory_list
```

Comment: `inventory_list.remove(items)` mutates a mutable object, which you then return. How exactly are you calling this function?

Comment: print() should take an argument, what are you trying to print?  you are reusing the count variable - maybe "for x in range(count)"

Comment: @flyingmeatball it's printing new lines

Comment: @flyingmeatball - `print()` doesn't need any arguments. An empty call prints a line with just a linefeed. And since `count` is not reused, it's technically okay to mask it for use as the loop variable (just like it's technically okay to use `type` as a variable name).

Comment: @cricket_007  good call.  Maybe do print('/n') to make it explicit?

Comment: @flyingmeatball - No. That would make it print two blank lines instead of just one.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 while it may be technically ok, certainly isn't best practice to use the same variable name. It's confusing to the reader - at least I was confused :)

Comment: what problems exactly do you have?

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 3):

Your inventory list doesn't have the new instance you are trying to remove. Just because it contains the same atrrs/values does not mean they are the same.

To be able to do this perhaps implement method `__eq__` in your SubPlant class:

```
class SubPlant(object):
    def __init__(self, type, name, price):
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```